# React Native app allow only 410 devices on Google Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I'm having trouble with the Google Play store that insists that my app is supported by 410 devices. i have uploaded app-x86-release.apk on Google and it shows Supported Android Devices 410 devices.  I've tried all the solutions I found in communities and elsewhere but no luck

AndroidManifest.xml :-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.animatedapp"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="true" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>                 
</manifest>
```

and build.gradle :-

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile



apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.animatedapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.6"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

       signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }


    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-custom-tabs')
    compile project(':react-native-cookie')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules     
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
    compile project(':ReactNativeChromeCustomTabs')
    compile project(':RNWebView')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's because you uploaded "app-x86-release.apk", it's APK for x86 architecture. Google Play Console shows me about 400 devices with x86 arch.

From your gradle file:

```
include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
```

Your application supports `armeabi-v7a` architecture, upload this build too.

Comment: Upload armeabi build to Google Play too. You should have "app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk" or something like it.

Comment: but I have also mentioned "X86" with "armeabi-v7a" in the code and uploaded app-x86-release.apk.

Comment: Yes. You uploaded it, that's ok. But there are not many devices with x86 architecture (~400). Most of devices have armeabi architecture. Upload armeabi build to Google Play too.